# redux reducer spread operator on array not replacing old state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

In my redux reducer I am updating a list of albums twice. I want the second list to overwrite the first list provided, however, this is not working and both album second call is adding to the first call.

Is there something I am not doing correctly with the spread operator below? Please see my reducer below.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

    case 'GET_ALBUM_NAME_SUCCESS':

        return [
            ...state,
            ...action.albums.map(album => {
                const newAlbum = {...album};
                delete(newAlbum.selections);
                return newAlbum;
            })
        ];

    default:

        return state;
}
```

Comment: Why is your state an array?

Comment: I think you really are looking for `return action.albums.map(({selections:_, ...newAlbum}) => newAlbum);`. Don't use `delete`!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a spread operator on the value that you want to add, provide you want to add values to the state,

```
export default (state = [], action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

    case 'GET_ALBUM_NAME_SUCCESS':

        return [
            ...state,
            action.albums.map(album => {
                const newAlbum = {...album};
                delete newAlbum.selections;
                return newAlbum;
            })
        ];

    default:

        return state;
}
```

However if you just want to overwrite the previous state, you don't need the spread operator at all.

```
export default (state = [], action) => {

    switch(action.type) {

    case 'GET_ALBUM_NAME_SUCCESS':

        return [
            action.albums.map(album => {
                const newAlbum = {...album};
                delete newAlbum.selections;
                return newAlbum;
            })
        ];

    default:

        return state;
}
```

Comment: Delete isn't a function, it's an operator, so those parens aren't needed and make it looks like something it isn't.

Comment: @loganfsmyth That's what I was wondering when I had a look at it. but as the problem wasn't there I assumed that it may be something that the OP has written

Comment: Yeah fair, just figured it was worth mentioning for the OP.